# What does "inspissated gloom" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Is ["inspissated"](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=cr&ei=gdmIV7v3OcP9UuCKvcgM#q=inspissated%20gloom&tbm=bks) used to simply emphasize the unhappiness/darkness? Is it used in literary contexts only? All the examples I have seen are either Biblical or literary.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inspissated)

> thickened in consistency; broadly :  made or having become thick, heavy, or intense

Comment: What research have you done? What do you understand "Inspissate" to mean?

Comment: Can you provide the context where you have seen this word used?  I have never heard of it or run across it in all my biblical or literary perusals.

Comment: @Catija just enter the phrase in google. https://www.google.ps/?gws_rd=cr&ei=gdmIV7v3OcP9UuCKvcgM#q=inspissated+gloom&tbm=bks

Comment: @Hellion I'm sorry the teacher only gave us the word, no definition, no explanation. He said it meant "a gloomy issue" but when I looked up inspissated I found out it meant thickened.

Comment: It's not **my** job to ask your question. You're asking about a very unusual word, it might be worth it to give us some sort of explanation.

Comment: @Catija I'm sorry, I have no context but the ones google provides. That's why I gave you the link.

Comment: It would be a good idea to **edit** your question and add that link, and to _quote_ some notable examples. That way, people do not have to ask for clarification in comments. The more information you give in your question, the better the answers will be.

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: Go to Google.  Type `define inspissate`.  What do you see??  Show us in your question that you have done this, and explain why what you found does not answer your question.

Answer (score 11):

It is not a common word in any register. In *Goodbye to All That* Robert Graves tells a story about T.E.Lawrence which illustrates this point:

> Professor Edgeworth, of All Souls’, avoided conversational English, persistently using words and phrases that one expects to meet only in books. One evening, Lawrence returned from a visit to London, and Edgeworth met him at the gate. 'Was it very caliginous in the Metropolis?'
>     'Somewhat caliginous, but not altogether inspissated', Lawrence replied gravely.

I am pretty widely read, and I have never encountered the word outside this context.

Comment: Seems like a term that'd be useful in cooking: "*Your sauce is a little thin, you need to inspissate it a bit more*"

Comment: I sometimes offer to inspissate the soup.

Comment: @Spehro I hope you're doing it with cornstarch or flour, or by reduction.

Comment: @StoneyB, I like to inspissate the soup via a process of micturition.

Comment: @dangph That's what I was afraid of. I suspect it's also contributed to the rarity of *inspissated*.

Comment: @dangph - i’d think that would tend to dilute or thin rather than inspissate...

Answer (score 7):

**Inspissated** is not only literary, it's actually a medical term as a dictionary tells you [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inspissated#medicalDictionary).

> **Medical Definition  of inspissated**
>   :  thick or thickened in consistency "blocked with inspissated bile" "the inspissated juices of an aloe"

However, connected with gloom it seems to be very rare and as you already discovered mainly in description of literary characters and literary scenarios.

Answer (score 7):

**[Inspissated](https://www.wordnik.com/words/inspissated)**

> thickened or dried by evaporation

Example of usage

> The poison is obtained by boiling the root in water, until it attains the consistency of an inspissated juice.

- Narrative Of Capt James Cook *Voyages Around the World*

**[Inspissated gloom](https://books.google.com.gt/books?id=yDBep9y0SVsC&pg=PA187&dq=%22inspissated%20gloom%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22inspissated%20gloom%22&f=false)**

This text was taken from *Eurekas and Euphorias: The Oxford book of Scientific Anecdotes*, and gives a very nice usage of the poetic sense.

[image]

Almost all usages I found were at least 100 to 150 years old.

Comment: upvote because yours is the only answer that even mentions gloom in an actual instance